# JSON error(s) with php backend

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I've never worked with JSON before and it's not going well...

I have a PHP script that returns a JSON array(is that the correct term?)
The script returns:
`{"items":1000,"mitems":0,"donations":0,"total":1000}`

NOTE: The script also sets the Content-Type to `application/json`

Here is my front-end javascript to handle that response:

```
function ajax(){
    $.ajax({
         url: '../ajax/goal_ajax.php',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function( data ){
          // success! :D
          alert('success');
         }, error: function( data ){
          // data.responseText is what you want to display, that's your error.
          alert(data.responseText);
         }
    })
    //progressBar.set('value',data.total);
    //document.getElementById('txtCDInfo').innerHTML=txt;
}
```

When that function is called I get an alert with the following message:
`{"items":1000,"mitems":0,"donations":0,"total":1000}`

If everything was successful, I should get an alert that says `success`, right?

Can someone please tell me what is going on here?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the problem, what doesn't work?

Comment: If everything went okay I should get an alert that says 'success', right?

Comment: are you throwing a content type header? e.g. `header('Content-Type: text/json')`

Comment: Did you set `Content-Type: application/json` on the response?

Comment: Is the `Content-Type` header set properly for goal_ajax.php?

Comment: yes, content-type is set in the php script before echoing the array

Comment: Technically, he doesn't even need the content-type header to be set to `json` since he's specifying `json` in `dataType`. Change `error: function( data )` to `error: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown)` and do `alert(textStatus)` to see the cause of the error.

Comment: responsetext is not error message. there is property or status for that error. dont remember top of my head. but If i were u i would find out what property contains error message.

Comment: Do you have access to the apache logs?  Are you sure the request is even being served appropriately?  Can you use firebug to test it out?

Comment: Firebug is king. As suggested in my answer and by @AJP, fix your error message to tell you more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the least documented thing in jquery what you need to do is alert the actual error in order to debug it. so do the following:

```
function my_ajax(){
    $.ajax({
         url: '/ajax/goal_ajax.php',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function( data ){
          // success! :D
          alert('success');
         }, error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          // data.responseText is what you want to display, that's your error.
          alert(jqXHR+","+textStatus+","+errorThrown);
         }
    })
    //progressBar.set('value',data.total);
    //document.getElementById('txtCDInfo').innerHTML=txt;
}
```

So two things I've done:

Change the name of the function (ajax is kinda a bad name :S) and improved the error reporting.

You should be getting the alert "success" yes. So something is going wrong.

EDIT:

Just noticed another thing, I dont think "../" would be a great way to reference the url, usually its either "/foo/ajax" which will allow you to use this function on any page.

Comment: okay, i implemented your function and it returned: `[object Object],parsererror,SyntaxError: Unexpected token ` so i/m guessing that means there is an error in the way the php script is parasing it?

Comment: what do you mean? That was returned in an alert, sorry I didnt clarify there.

Comment: Check your <script> tags and make sure you haven't got any trailing "<" or ">" anywhere. Also, it would seem maybe the php script is going wrong. Try the actual link without the ajax function. ie browse to example.com/ajax/goal_ajax.php like you would a normal website. You might see an error coming from php

Answer (score 2):

It could be that your PHP script returns an error status code and even though it prints out the correct result, it still fails. I tested your scripts on my system and I got the 'success' alert. Then I changed my PHP script to the following:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json', true, 401); 
echo '{"items":1000,"mitems":0,"donations":0,"total":1000}';
?>
```

Note that the third parameter of the header function sets the http response code to 401 - Even though the correct output is sent back to the client; officially, the request has failed because of that status code. After running this code, I got the exact same problem as you.

So in summary, there might be something in your script which is causing a non-fatal error which doesn't show in the output of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Are you defining the MIME type in your HTTP response?

Try adding a Content-type header to the output of your script.

```
<?php
...
    $output = json_encode(...);
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo $output;
...
?>
```

You can also try using the mimeType parameter in your $.ajax() call to override the response type.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax

Are you running your PHP scripts under Apache or on their own (chmod u+x on the script)? You probably need to use a PHP framework such as Zend, CodeIgniter or CakePHP and define a controller action that handles your AJAX request to have a proper HTTP response.

Answer (score 0):

As the guy above me said, you should be using the json_encode(); function in PHP then echo'ing that output.
Make sure you encode an array though:

```
    <?
      $send = array(
                  'items' => '1000',
                  'mitems' => '0', 
                  'donations' => '0', 
                  'total' => '1000',
                );

      echo json_encode($send);
    ?>
```